# RESTful API filter data by list of filters

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, filtering

I am creating a RESTful API to return a lot of data. Now I want to filter this data by the selected filters from a list. There are more than 150 options.

The user can select the filters link this:
[image]

My question is, how can I apply those filters without having 150+ if statements.

The downside of the database is that those filters are not stored directly in the database but are defined by a set of numbers (dataSource, dataCode).

I hope anyone can help me by finding the best practice.

I am creating the API with Django with Rest framework

UPDATE:
I have a Event model, which has: id, text, dataSource, dataCode, starttime.
This model needs to be filtered. The dataSource and dataCode determains the filters

Comment: What does your current db/model look like? What's the expected output? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Currently I only could thing of 150+ if's but I don't think that's the best way. I updated the question.